# Find the number of subarrays in an array which has the given sum

Tags: javascript

Here is the problem: Find the number of subarrays in an array, which has the given sum.

this program enter 2 parameters number array and sum.

**for example:
subArrayCnt([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5)**

and the output should be number of subarrays accoding to given sum. 
(output should be 3 for above example {2,3}, {3,2}, {8,-3} (number of subarrays))

I tried to do that but there is a problem with it isn't fulfilling the requirment of "The answer should be valid for any given input"

Here is my code:

```
function subArrayCnt(arr, sum) {
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var str = [];
        var csum= 0;
        var output = 0;

for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {        
        csum+= arr[j];
        str.push(arr[j]);
        if (csum== sum) {       
              return(str[i]);     
             }
         }
     }
}

console.log(subArrayCnt([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5));
```

this program provide number of subarrays but it isn't fulfilling the requirment of "The answer should be valid for any given input" where should be corrected? any suggetions please.

Comment: what about `1,2,3,2,-3` and `2,3,2,1,-3`?

Comment: here the answer should be valid for any given input also negative numbers should me accept

Comment: Why you are returning ` return(str[i]); `?

Comment: for getting the number of element in str. is it the wrong way?

Comment: @SoWeLaugh_ no, these are the numbers from your input array and they also have a sum of 5. Are these valid results? If not, why not? What defines a valid result?

Comment: You only want to check sum of two numbers.And also tell that numbers are always adjacent or they can be from anywhere in array?

Comment: here is my requirements:  getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5) should equal to 3.   , getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,4],10) should equal to 1. and The answer should be valid for any given input.

Comment: @MaheerAli adjacent numbers only

Comment: @SoWeLaugh _ I got your problem. I have answered ask if its not working

Comment: @MaheerAli  getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5) should equal to 3. , getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,4],10) these 2 is ok but not fulfill the last requiement "The answer should be valid for any given input."  yes of course i need your help please.

Comment: @SoWeLaugh _ Give example where its not working

Answer (score 1):

The other answers seem to be ignoring the fact that the sum can be obtained from any number of elements of the array.  Recursion is the best approach here.

```js
function subArrayCnt(arr, sum){
  return subArrayRecurse(arr, sum, 0, [], 0)
}

function subArrayRecurse(arr, sum, currentSum, curArray, i){
  var count = 0;
  //check the current index
  var newSum = currentSum + arr[i];
  var newSubArray = curArray.concat([arr[i]]);
  if(newSum == sum) {
    console.log('found another: ' + newSubArray);
    count++;
  }
  if(i + 1 < arr.length) {
    //try including the current in further sums
    count += subArrayRecurse(arr, sum, newSum, newSubArray, i + 1);
    //try not including the current in further sums
    count += subArrayRecurse(arr, sum, currentSum, curArray, i + 1);
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(subArrayCnt([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5));
// 8
```

The 8 combos from the above example are:

```
1,2,3,2,-3
1,2,2
1,3,1
2,3
2,3,2,1,-3
2,2,1
3,2
8,-3
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I assumed that the sum of two consecutive elements should be the sum to qualify.

```
function subArrayCnt(arr, sum) {
    let outputArr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]+arr[i+1]==sum){
            let obj = {l:arr[i],r:arr[i+1]};
            outputArr.push(obj);
        }
    };
    return outputArr.length;
};
```

Comment: in here if we give subArrayCnt([1,2,3,4],10) answer should be 1. but it will give 0.

Comment: Should [1,2,3,0,4] return 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
function subArrayCnt(arr, sum){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
    for(var n = i+1; n < arr.length; n++){
      if(arr[i] + arr[n] == sum){
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(subArrayCnt([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5));
// 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using nested loop. This will get all the possible adjacent sums and then you can compare that sum with the given sum and increase `count`.

```js
function func(arr,sum){
  if(!Array.isArray(arr)) return 0;
  let count = 0;
  let cur = 0;
  for(let i = 0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
    cur = arr[i];
    for(let j = i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
      cur += arr[j];
      if(cur === sum){
        count++;
        break;
      }
      if(cur > sum) break;
    }
  }
  return count+'';
}

console.log(func([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5)) //3
console.log(func([1,2,3,4],10)) //1
```

Comment: getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5) should equal to 3. , getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,4],10) these 2 is ok but not fulfill the last requirement "The answer should be valid for any given input."  and there is a tip in problem say "please consider the adjacent numbers only"

Comment: @SoWeLaugh _ Give link to problem I would see it.

Comment: the link is not working to external users that is the problem. here is the problem as in  site.   Find the number of subarrays in an array, which has the given sum. (tip: please consider the adjacent numbers only)

Example :

Input getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5)

Output should be 3  example combinations ({2,3}, {3,2}, {8,-3})  and these are the requirment to be fulfill: The return type should be a string.
subArrayCnt([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5) should equal to 3.
subArrayCnt([1,2,3,4],10) should equal to 1.
The answer should be valid for any given input.

Comment: @SoWeLaugh _ I have edit the code that will check element is array or not. Can you please tell **for what particular input its not working**

Comment: @SoWeLaugh _ The return value should be string. I edited the code now test it

Comment: please kindly can you check it with that site I have sent.. everything is ok.. but it was told: "The answer should be valid for any given input."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<script>
  function subArray(arr,sum)
{
    var subArray=new Array();
    count=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
     if(arr[i]+arr[i+1]==sum)
        {
          subArray[count]=[arr[i],arr[i+1]]
           count++;       
        }
    }
    return subArray;
}

console.log(subArray([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I wrote this function. It fulfill the requirement of "The answer should be valid for any given input".

```
function getSubArrayCount(arr, sum){

   if(!Array.isArray(arr)) return 0;

   var len = arr.length;
   var count = 0;

   for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
      var n = 0;
     
      for(var j = i; j < len; j++){    
         n += arr[j];
      
         if(n === sum) {
           count++;
           break;
         }
      }
   }

   return count;
}

getSubArrayCount([1,2,3,2,1,8,-3],5);
```